# Where can I find depth_Astra_Orbbec.yaml?

Tags: ros, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Where can I find depth_Astra_Orbbec.yaml file? I googled it but doesn't seem it is available anywhere.
I am using Astra camera, and I see these warnings.

I am trying to debug why the amcl doesn't work.
Any clue?

> [ INFO] [1488843778.299006266]: Device
> "2bc5/0401@1/4" found. Warning: USB
> events thread - failed to set
> priority. This might cause loss of
> data... [ WARN]
> [1488843783.053552017]: Timed out
> waiting for transform from
> base_footprint to map to become
> available before running costmap, tf
> error: . canTransform returned after
> 0.101375 timeout was 0.1. [ INFO] [1488843783.308797123]: Starting depth
> stream. [ INFO]
> [1488843783.422696518]: using default
> calibration URL [ INFO]
> [1488843783.423527793]: camera
> calibration URL:
> file:///home/habals/.ros/camera_info/depth_Astra_Orbbec.yaml
> [ INFO] [1488843783.424577380]: Unable
> to open camera calibration file
> [/home/habals/.ros/camera_info/depth_Astra_Orbbec.yaml]
> [ WARN] [1488843783.425319542]: Camera
> calibration file
> /home/habals/.ros/camera_info/depth_Astra_Orbbec.yaml
> not found. [ WARN]
> [1488843788.151544033]: Timed out
> waiting for transform from
> base_footprint to map to become
> available before running costmap, tf
> error: . canTransform returned after
> 0.101699 timeout was 0.1. [ WARN] [1488843793.242873100]: Timed out
> waiting for transform from
> base_footprint to map to become
> available before running costmap, tf
> error: . canTransform returned after
> 0.101175 timeout was 0.1. [ WARN] [1488843798.339849246]: Timed out
> waiting for transform from
> base_footprint to map to become
> available before running costmap, tf
> error: . canTransform returned after
> 0.101268 timeout was 0.1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256300/where-can-i-find-depth_astra_orbbec.yaml?/) by [kangnamtofu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29441/kangnamtofu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2017-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thuan98](https://answers.ros.org/users/44325/thuan98/) on 2019-07-27**:
rviz sometimes can get pointcloud2 from astrapro camera.help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/habals/.ros/camera_info/depth_Astra_Orbbec.yaml]

This is not a file that is provided for you, but one that you have to generate using (fi) the [camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration) tool. That tool will perform an intrinsic calibration, which is what the node can't find. If it can't find it, it'll just use a default (ie: uncalibrated) one, which will most likely not work too well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kangnamtofu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29441/kangnamtofu/) on 2017-03-09**:
Thank you so much!
I got the rgb camera calibrated using the camera_calibration tool, but I cannot find how to calibrate the depth camera. It looks depth sensor is also way off now.

**Comment by [salocinx](https://answers.ros.org/users/34650/salocinx/) on 2018-04-15**:
same problem here :-/ do you have found any solution?